# I want to call javascript confirm dialog using AddResource

Tags: java, javascript, apache, jsf, facelets

I want to call javascript from JSF back bean function.

for that i have used **org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.util.AddResou**rce (tomahawk-1.1.3.jar).

```
String javaScriptText = "return confirm('hi');";

            AddResource addResource = AddResourceFactory.getInstance(context);
            addResource.addInlineScriptAtPosition(context, AddResource.HEADER_BEGIN, javaScriptText);
```

it call javascript but with error.it can call simply alert dialog but not confirm dialog.

Answer (score 0):

If you *actually* want a confirmation dialogue and be able to block the button's default action, you have to attach it to the `click` event of the button, not to execute it during page load.

```
<h:commandButton value="delete" action="#{bean.delete}" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" />
```